# Operation on specific columns in R

Tags: r

more a curiosity than a question. Is it possible to make some operation only on specific columns of a dataframe but maintaining the dataframe original structure?

For example, suppose I want simply to add 1 to the first 4 columns of the iris dataset because the 5th column is a factor and it is nonsense to add values to it.

**1. ignoring the factor column**

just perform the operation without caring of the Warning Message

```
ex <- iris[,] + 1
head(ex, 2)
#gives
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          6.1         4.5          2.4         1.2      NA
2          5.9         4.0          2.4         1.2      NA
```

so the 5th original column loose the original values due to the nonsense operation.

**2. excluding the last column**

excluding the index of the column from the operation

```
ex <- iris[,-c(5)] + 1
head(ex, 2)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          6.1         4.5          2.4         1.2
2          5.9         4.0          2.4         1.2
```

but doing so I have to perform a `cbind` operation to recover the original column (not a big deal with this dataframe)

I was wondering if there is a smarter solution for this operation. Imagine the dataframe is very big,with `cbind` one loose the original position of the columns and it could be quite tricky to do it.

Thanks to all

Comment: `ex <- iris; ex[,-c(5)] <- ex[,-c(5)] + 1; head(ex)` Assign back to the same name.

Comment: How about `library(dplyr); iris %>% mutate_each(funs(.+1), -Species)`

Comment: You could also use a index. `indx=sapply(iris, is.numeric);
iris[indx] <- lapply(iris[indx], function(x) x+1)`

Comment: @Sotos Then I would go for `iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(.+1))`

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli The main problem is that OP assign the result to a new name, hence loosing the last column.

Comment: @Axeman yeah that is more generic

Comment: @Tensibai: yeah we need to assign the same df to a new df. so that we can get back the original columns.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli (side note, why using lapply here ?, `iris[indx] + 1` should do)

Comment: @Tensibai:it obsession with lapply i guess. i will keep that in mind.

Comment: thanks for all the comments and solutions proposed. Both Tensibai and Sotos are good solutions.